# How can I identify and debug digital audio bitstream formats?

Tags: audio, music

I hope this is the right forum - I looked at all the Stack Exchange communities, and this seems the best fit...

As a musician, engineer, and home AV enthusiast, I encounter various digital audio bitstreams from stereo SPDIF to Dolby Digital 5.1, to DTS, Atmos, etc.
These can be transported over various physical media - Coax, Optical, HDMI.
When things don't work, I find I spend an excessive amount of time debugging.

I'm looking for a tool to help diagnose these bitstreams better than trial and error - answering the questions: is there a signal, and if so, what is the type?

Such a tool could be implemented as standalone hardware or software that runs on Linux or Windows. Even a Raspberry Pi should have sufficient capability to identify the bitstream.
I've been searching and have found nothing like this.

If I have to roll my own, the best information I found (on DD only) is at [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dolby_Digital) which links to the [ATSC AC-3 standard](http://www.atsc.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/A52-201212-17.pdf) That also points to a decoder [liba52](https://liba52.sourceforge.io/) which was last updated in 2002. Can anyone offer better suggestions on a place to start?

Comment: A nice AudioPrecision audio analyzer with the appropriate interfaces (https://www.ap.com/analyzers-accessories/interfaces-modules/) will do the job. Not cheap, though.

Comment: As @audionuma points out, there exists test equipment in the $$$$ price range. As far as I can determine there is nothing available in terms of DIY hardware or open source software.  One option of last resort is to buy a cheap receiver with the appropriate inputs, and look at the front panel display. Not very compact or convenient, though.

Comment: I ran across this post on a [DIY SPDIF transceiver](https://hackaday.com/2021/12/06/adding-optical-audio-to-the-raspberry-pi-with-one-chip/
) for the Raspberry Pi. It is out of stock unfortunately. It tells me there may be some built-in SPDIF decoding capabilities already in the Pi. I'll study and report back.